# Android app and using php/mysql as a Restful solution

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am creating an android app that will use the database intensely and use a lot of Json to read the output from the database over the internet. I know that PHP is an interpreted language but would this cause an issue when creating an android app from a performance standpoint when you have many users? or would I be better off with Java/MySQL. I know both PHP and Java just thinking long term here.

Comment: Do you have any **real** problems? or just hypothetical?

Comment: You can use English Language for backend.

Comment: what does it matter that php is interpreted? you'll probably find that a majority of your time will be spent waiting for the network, rather than php itself (unless you're doing some massive back-end computations).

Comment: Raheel if you have nothing constructive to say about my question then please don't comment. It is hypothetical Selvin I am new at this just trying to educate myself.  Oh ok Marc in that case I will go with PHP since it is much easier to prototype on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP works fine with huge number of users. It definitely wins for rapid development and release. You can scale your servers when the need arises. Imo, use any language/framework you are most comfortable.

Comment: Oh ok Thanks for answering in that case I will go with php. I was just confused because certain people on the web make it a big deal on the whole interpreted vs. compiled argument.